# How to make a JavExec task incremental in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, incremental-build

I have a JavaExec task in my build.gradle file and it doesn't follow incremental build.

Is there a way to make JavaExec tasks incremental, just like how JavaCompile tasks are made incremental?

Let me know your thoughts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a custom task type that extends `JavaExec`, then you could add the `@CacheableTask` annotation:

```
@CacheableTask
public abstract class MyCustomTask extends JavaExec { }
```

Another approach if it is just a `JavaExec` task, as described in the Javadocs:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/work/DisableCachingByDefault.html

> Caching for individual task instances can be enabled and disabled via `TaskOutputs.cacheIf(String, Spec)` or disabled via `TaskOutputs.doNotCacheIf(String, Spec)`. Using these APIs takes precedence over the presence (or absence) of `@DisableCachingByDefault`.

```
tasks.register<JavaExec>("myTask") {
    outputs.cacheIf {
        // some condition...
    }
}
```